# Sequelize: Using LIKE on DATE

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

We are creating search functionality for our app. We need to be able to search on dates. For example, a user might want to find all records where the Sale Date is 2018. In our DB the Sale Date is a DATE type. Is there a way to use the LIKE keyword on DATE?

I'd ideally like the WHERE clause to look like this:

`` findAll({where: {SaleDate: {like: `%${searchString}%`}}) ``

We are using SQLServer for our DB.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `like` on dates.  `like` is for strings and strings are not dates.

In general, I think "start date" and "end date" is sufficient for most purposes.  Every so often you may need customized approaches, such as for a particular day of the week or day of the month.

Answer (score -2):

I using NODE and MongoDB, if date has been stored in DATE type. Then you ca use $year function of Mongo.

Here is the link, showing how to use $year
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/

Some of the examples are :

{ $year: new Date("2016-01-01") } // 2016.

This can be used in find query to get the required result.